# What does `omega` really do here?

Tags: coq

This proof can be finished with a single `omega`:

```
  a : Z
  b : Z                                                                                               
  H : a > 1
  H0 : b > 1
  H1 : b = 1                                                                                          
  H2 : a mod b = 0
  ============================
   False
```

Why is that? What does `omega` really do here? And since `H0` and `H1` contradict each other, shouldn't it be possible to prove anything? Also, can this be proved without `omega`? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1- Here, `omega` realizes that `H0` and `H1` are contradictory and uses them to produce a proof of `False`. It shouldn't be hard to show this directly by rewriting `H1` into `H0` (which results in `1 > 1`), then apply some lemma that shows that `a > b -> a <> b`, resulting in `1 <> 1`, and then apply to our goal, resulting in a new goal `1 = 1`, which can be discharged by `reflexivity`. It's hard to describe *how* `omega` works in detail, since it has a complicated algorithm behind it, that can deal with a large class of similar goals (roughly speaking, [Presburger arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic))

2- Yes. `H0` and `H1` can be used to prove anything, including `False`. This is sometimes referred to as the [Principle of explosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion). Note, however, that you're only able to prove anything *inside that specific context*. Put otherwise, it is not because you had a contradiction in *some* proof context that you're able to prove *anything else*.

Answer (score 3):

You can figure out what any tactic has done by showing the proof term it generated.

```
Require Import Omega.

Definition how : forall (a : Z), (a > 1)%Z -> (a = 1)%Z -> False.
intros.
omega.
Qed.

Print how.

(* Here are the library functions "how" uses on my machine: *)

Check fast_Zplus_assoc_reverse.
Check fast_Zred_factor0.
Check fast_OMEGA15.
Check fast_Zred_factor5.
Check OMEGA6.
Check Zegal_left.
Check Zgt_left.
```

You can also prove this yourself without any fancy machinery:

```
Locate "_ > _".
Print Z.gt.
Locate "_ ?= _".
Print Z.compare.

Definition this : forall (a : Z), (a > 1)%Z -> (a = 1)%Z -> False.
Proof with (subst; simpl in *; auto).
intros...
unfold Z.gt in * ...
unfold Pos.compare in * ...
inversion H.
Qed.

Print this.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look up `omega` in the Coq manual, you will see the reference to [Bill Pugh's "The Omega Test: a fast and practical integer programming algorithm for dependence analysis"](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~pingali/CS380C/2013/papers/pugh92omega.pdf), which should explain what `omega` is doing, roughly.